# Not getting color value from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to copy a Pie Chart from sample which I have downloaded from internet and add it in my project but i am not getting the colors

This Actual view of downloaded source code

https://goo.gl/o27nsQ

this is what I am getting.

https://goo.gl/UpQojP

Original Code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.benliger.chart"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp" >

 <com.benliger.chart.view.PieDonutChart
    android:id="@+id/pie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    custom:colorCircleInside="@android:color/white"
    custom:highlightStrength="1.15"
    custom:ratioCircleInside="0.8" />

 </LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/change_data" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/seekBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radius" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="80" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My code

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.apptitude"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp" >

 <com.example.chart.view.PieDonutChart
    android:id="@+id/pie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    custom:colorCircleInside="@android:color/white"
    custom:highlightStrength="1.15"
    custom:ratioCircleInside="0.8" />

 </LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/change_data" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/seekBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radius" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="80" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have u added values in your res folder?

Comment: there is a class file PieDonutChart @com.benliger.chart.view package

Comment: Are you using android studio or eclipse?

Comment: did you checked the java part of that PieChart example project? I'm pretty sure the colors are added in the java code.

Comment: Yes colors are added from java code.

Comment: Can you show us the example / your java code for the colors?

Comment: dont know how but it is working now thank you guys :)